# How to view changes in GitHub after comments

Tags: github, github-for-windows

Is there a way to view changes that were made after a code review by other developers?

Say, someone suggested a change and commented in GitHub on a specific file.

- PR creator made changes to that specific file and checked in. - Is there a way to view that change?

[image]

Clicking view changes doesn't take me directly to the file that has comments. It takes me to all the files

This feature was very useful in BitBucket, as I could see all the changes of that specific file and comments in one place. Seems it's missing in GitHub.

This did not help:
https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/reviewing-proposed-changes-in-a-pull-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Reviewing proposed changes in a pull request" you mention (as not helping) should still include a `Jump to` link:

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/pull_requests/file-filter-menu.png]

That should allow you to narrow the list of files, and select the one you want to go to immediately.